# Set Unix env variables using a perl script

Tags: perl

I am trying to load Unix env variables for the current session using a perl script.
The env variables are defined manually once and then they are stored in files-output of the env command.
Reason I am trying this is because there are a number of variables that need to be set and it is difficult to fish for the variables everytime in the text files and set them.

This is part of my env file:

```
    PYTHONPATH=:/usr/local/lib/python-lib:/usr/local/lib/python-lib/ptml: /usr/local/lib/python-lib/rbs:/usr/local/lib/python-lib/vsspy
RBUILDS=/vol.nas/u00/builds
RIDE_HOME=/vol.nas/rpas_qc/mohima/MOCKS/RPAS/tools
RIDE_OPTIONS= -d64
RPAS_HOME=/vol.nas/rpas_qc/mohima/MOCKS/RPAS/rpas
RPAS_JAVA_CLASSPATH=/vol.nas/rpas_qc/mohima/MOCKS/RPAS/rpas/lib/oracleRpasUtils.jar
```

My perl script goes like this:

```
    open FILE, "/vol.nas/rpas_qc/mohima/MOCKS/env_15" or die;
my %hash;
while (<FILE>)
{
   chomp;
    ($key, $val) = split /=/;
   $hash{$key} = $val;
}
#foreach  $i(keys %hash){
 print "export RIDE_HOME=$hash{RIDE_HOME}\n";

 print "export RPAS_JAVA_CLASSPATH=$hash{RPAS_JAVA_CLASSPATH}\n";
```

If I run this from my shell:

```
eval 'perl text2hash.pl': (name of the script is text2hash.pl)
```

This seems to work fine. I can echo my env variables and see the values.

However what I wanted, is to export all the env variables without specifying them. So in my perl script , if I have:

```
open FILE, "/vol.nas/rpas_qc/mohima/MOCKS/env_15" or die;
my %hash;
while (<FILE>)
{
   chomp;
    ($key, $val) = split /=/;
   $hash{$key} = $val;
}
*foreach  $i(keys %hash){
print "export $i=$hash{$i}\n";*
}
```

And then if I run the same eval command as before, I am getting an error message:

```
-ksh: eval[1]: export: 53553: is not an identifier
```

So basically, if I specify the key name for the hash inside the print command, then the eval seems to work, but if I try to loop through the hash to export the key values the eval gives an error.

Can anyone please help on this?

Comment: This is a bad idea. First off, your Perl program is running in a subshell, and changes will be discarded when the program exits. Second, your shell is subject to changes from a lot of processes and will retain values that might be incorrect later on. And also, why would it be easier to "fish for" values in the shell than in a file?

Comment: PYTHONPATH=:/usr/local/lib/python-lib:/usr/local/lib/python-lib/ptml: /usr/local/lib/python-lib/rbs:/usr/local/lib/python-lib/vsspy
RBUILDS=/vol.nas/u00/builds
RIDE_HOME=/vol.nas/rpas_qc/mohima/MOCKS/RPAS/tools
RIDE_OPTIONS= -d64
RPAS_HOME=/vol.nas/rpas_qc/mohima/MOCKS/RPAS/rpas
RPAS_JAVA_CLASSPATH=/vol.nas/rpas_qc/mohima/MOCKS/RPAS/rpas/lib/oracleRpasUtils.jarThis is part of my input file: @Сухой27

Comment: @TLP, the first time the env variables are set manually. And then the variables are stored in a file(output of env command). Everytime we logon again we need to look at this file and then set the same values for our variables. Instead of this, I am trying to read this file into a hash(env var is the key with the corresponding values) and then run 'print export ...'commands inside my perl script.

Comment: @TLP When I run eval `perlscript`, I can see that my env variables are set correctly, but that is only when I specify the env var name inside my perl script; so this works: print "export RIDE_HOME=$hash{RIDE_HOME}\n"; but this does not :*foreach  $i(keys %hash){
print "export $i=$hash{$i}\n";*
}

Comment: @MohimaChaudhuri I guess you are getting spaces in some of keys or may in some of values also like `RIDE_OPTIONS= -d64 `. So consider trimming them  i.e `$val=~s/^\s*|\s*$//g`.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you're trying to do this in the first place is indicative of a larger problem, and this is almost certainly not the best way to go about solving it. However, since we don't have enough information to get to the actual root cause, it's impossible to suggest a better solution. We can at least suggest a *shorter* solution, though:

```
eval `perl -lne 'print "export $_"' /vol.nas/rpas_qc/mohima/MOCKS/env_15`
```

You've already got your input in `key=value` format---there's no need to split on `=` and then reconstitute the lines without any further processing.

Now, if you've got duplicate variable names and you're trying to make them unique, a hash would be the appropriate data structure to use. However, it makes no difference in this case, because the shell will do exactly the same thing Perl will do (overwrite existing values with later assignments).